# Return number when the number = 0

Tags: ios, swift, numbers

My app has a button and the button makes a label decrees from 5 to 1 (5..4..3..2..1). What I want is return to 5 again when the number gets to 0. I have tried this but is does not work. Does anyone have any tips?

```
@IBOutlet weak var NbrLabel: UILabel!

var Nbr = 5
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if Nbr == 0 {
        Nbr == 5
        NbrLabel.text = "\(Nbr)"

    }
}

@IBAction func ICButton(sender: UIButton) {
    Nbr -= 1
    NbrLabel.text = "\(Nbr)"
}
```

Comment: the assigment should be `Nbr = 5`, remove the double `=`!

Comment: *" is does not work"* – Then learn how to debug a program.

Comment: Variables should start with a lowercase letter: `nbr`, `nbrLabel`.  The reason they are blue above is that syntax highlighting thinks they are Class names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
@IBOutlet weak var NbrLabel: UILabel!

var Nbr = 5

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

@IBAction func ICButton(sender: UIButton) {
    Nbr -= 1

    if Nbr == 0 {

        Nbr = 5
    }

    NbrLabel.text = "\(Nbr)"
}
```

Are you beginning with programing?

Comment: You might want to leave `NbrLabel.text = "\(Nbr)"` in `viewDidLoad` so that the label gets a value before a button has been pushed.

Comment: @DavidSundström, I only left the comment. User t4nhpt provided the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I am new:)

Answer (score 2):

The check for equivalence to max number (5 in your case) should be done in IBAction method. In viewDidLoad method you should only set up label with the initial value that will be displayed after your view loads (if you have single view application - on your application start). Try such variant:

```
let NbrMaxValue = 5

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var NbrLabel: UILabel!
    var Nbr = NbrMaxValue
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        NbrLabel.text = "\(Nbr)"
    }

    @IBAction func ICButton(sender: UIButton) {
        --Nbr
        if Nbr == 0 { Nbr = NbrMaxValue }
        NbrLabel.text = "\(Nbr)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.. I know this has an accepted answer already but counting backwards can be thought of as -

```
 5 - 0 = 5
 5 - 1 = 4
 5 - 2 = 3
 5 - 3 = 2
 5 - 4 = 1
```

therefor rather using an if statement why not just increment a counter and use modulus expression like -

```
var counter = 4 // initial value to start with

var value = 5 - ((counter + 1) % 5) // execute this line on button press
```

note - this is just an example to demonstrate counting backwards without using if statements checking for zero.